# Sympy - got two solutions from trigonometric equation, I was expecting only one

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve a trigonometric equation with sympy. I'm having issues understanding what sympy is doing: I was expecting only one solution, instead I got two. Here is the code:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.var("a, b, c, d, z")
myeq = sp.Eq(c * sp.sin(a * (b / 2 - z)) + d * sp.cos(a * (b / 2 - z)), 0)
sol = sp.solve(myeq, z)
print(sol)

Output: [(a*b - 4*atan((c - sqrt(c**2 + d**2))/d))/(2*a), (a*b - 4*atan((c + sqrt(c**2 + d**2))/d))/(2*a)]
```

The solution I was expecting is: `[b / 2 + atan(c / d) / a]`

What am I missing? For this specific case, is it possible to obtain a single solution?

Comment: +/- sqrt solutions are common.  Consider the basic quadratic formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: @hpaulj they are common if the equation is a quadratic. My equation does not appear to be so...

Comment: An approach to understand what's happening is to give constant values to some of a,b,c,d and see what happens. Try to find the simplest equation that gives an unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rearrange your equation to combine the `sin` and `cos` into `tan` you will get what you are looking for:

```
>>> solve(c/d*tan(a*(b/2-z))-1,z)
[b/2 - atan(d/c)/a]
```

If you don't, SymPy will rewrite and solve in terms of `exp`...and in that case, as you can verify, it will be quadratic in `exp(l*a*z)`.

An attempt at rewriting a two-arg sum as a ratio could be done like this:

```
>>> def ratio(eq):
...     if isinstance(eq, Eq):
...         eq=eq.rewrite(Add)
...     A, B = eq.as_two_terms()
...     if not A.is_Add and not B.is_Add:
...         return Eq(A/B, 1)
>>> trigsimp(ratio(eq))
Eq(c*tan(a*b/2 - a*z)/d, 1)
```

(The function returns None if there aren't two terms to work with.) As you can see, in this case you get a new equation which will solve as you desired.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes perfectly sense! Do you think it would be possible to identify that kind of occurence and apply the rearrangement step automatically? Is there any sympy's methods that could help?

Comment: updated answer with a suggestion for more automation

Comment: I'm trying to understand how sympy deals with trigonometry. Say I start with `myeq` as given above. Basically, Sympy does `myeq.rewrite(exp)` than solve for `z`? If so, a list of 2 solutions involving logarithms is computed. How does it convert it back to the 2 solutions containing `atan`?

Comment: You could try tracing the code path of `solve` to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: I did searched indeed, but the only expression that is going to be rewritten in terms of exponentials are the Hyperbolic functions! That led me to open a [question over math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521465/trigonometric-equation-solved-with-exponential-functions/), where I finally realized that sympy is not rewriting that equation in terms of exponential function! Thank you anyway for you directions! :)

Comment: Interesting discussion there!

Comment: Note, too, that with SymPy you can use `.rewrite(tan)` just like `.rewrite(exp)`.